# Не могу разобраться с ошибкой syntax error, unexpected $end in on line 48

Tags: php

```
<?php
        $hostname = "localhost"; // название/путь сервера, с MySQL
        $username = "root"; // имя пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию "root")
        $password = ""; // пароль пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию пароль отсутствует, этот параметр можно оставить пустым)
        $dbName = "bd"; // название базы данных

        /* Создаем соединение */
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");
        mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or header('Location: Error');

        /* Выбираем базу данных. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее */
        mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());

    $name = $_REQUEST['type'];
    $query= "select * from price_svai where name like \'$name%'\";

    $result = MYSQL_QUERY($query);


    $number = MYSQL_NUMROWS($result);

    $i = 0;
    IF ($number == 0)
    {

    }
        ELSEIF ($number > 0) 
        {
            PRINT '<table class='bordered bordered2'>';
            PRINT '<TR><TD>Толщина стенки м.м.</TD><TD>Диаметр лопасти м.м.</TD><TD>Толщина лопасти м.м.</TD><TD>Длина ствола м.м.</TD><TD>Руб. за шт.</TD></TR>';
    WHILE ($i < $number)
    {
        $numb = mysql_result($result,$i,'numb');
        $name= mysql_result($result,$i,'name');
        $dia= mysql_result($result,$i,'dia');
        $width = mysql_result($result,$i,'width');
        $dialop = mysql_result($result,$i,'dialop');
        $widthlop = mysql_result($result,$i,'widthlop');
        $dlinast = mysql_result($result,$i,'dlinast');
        $price = mysql_result($result,$i,'price');

        PRINT '<TR><TD>$width</TD><TD>$dialop</TD><TD>$widthlop</TD><TD>$dlinast</TD><TD>$price</TD></TR>';
        $i++;
    };
PRINT '</table>';
PRINT '</CENTER>';
};
?>
```

Ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in on line 48

short_open_tag = On;

Comment: Снимите экраны с кавычек в запросе  $query= "select * from price_svai where name like '$name%'";

Comment: не смущает? `'$name%'`

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените ваш запрос на такую строчку:

```
$query= "select * from price_svai where name like '".$name."%'";
```